# Foreach loop display only last record in chart of canvas and php json cannot used in javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am display sales report using canvas and i want to display sum of product sale date wise query get result but due to forecah loop i am getting last record only.I am getting four record from controller but in blade file i found only last record.

Controller:

```
public function display_sales_report(Request $req)
    {
        $data=$req->all();
        $get_details=DB::select('SELECT sum(orders_qty) as sum_of_qty,deliver_date FROM `orders` WHERE deliver_date between ? AND ? GROUP BY deliver_date',[$data['start_date'],$data['end_date']]);
        return view('dashboard',['get_data'=>$get_details]);
    }
```

Blade file
:

```
<?php

 $getDetails=array();
 foreach($get_data as $data)
 {
  $dataPoints = array( 
    array("y" => $data->sum_of_qty, "label" => $data->deliver_date)
    );
 }

?>
 <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    theme: "light2",
    title:{
        text: "Sales Report"
    },
    axisY: {
        title: "Number of product sold"
    },
    data: [{
        type: "column",
        yValueFormatString: "#,##0.## tonnes",
        dataPoints: <?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
    }]
});
chart.render();

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting data to `$dataPoints` in each loop. You need to put every data in each loop like this:

```php
foreach($get_data as $data)
{
    $dataPoints[] = array("y" => $data->sum_of_qty, "label" => $data->deliver_date);
}
```

And in your javascript code, you need to use `JSON.parse()` parse the **php json** string to **javascript array**:

```js
JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($dataPoints, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>)
```

Comment: hello I am using this but it can not display graph plz check java script code i am pass this for each data to json encode

Comment: @smitaranipatil try to use `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 0):

Definitely!, because you are just re assigned the value of your datapoints variable rather of pushing the new value on datapoints. Your code should like this.

```
foreach($get_data as $data)
{
    $dataPoints[] = array("label" => $dat->deliver_date, "y" => $data->sum_of_qty);
}
```

Comment: hello I am using this but it can not display graph plz check java script code i am pass this for each data to json encode

Comment: why you are converting it json_encode ? it will convert to string. Just use JSON.parse($dataPoints);

Comment: change your dataPoints to this, dataPoints: JSON.parse("{{json_encode($dataPoints)}}")

Comment: (2/2) ErrorException
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\avitra\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php) I am getting this error

Comment: this one,  dataPoints: "{{$dataPoints}}" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207643/discussion-between-qonvex620-and-smitarani-patil).